# How to horizontally (or vertically) flip the contents of an SDL2 window with PySDL2?

Tags: python, sdl-2, pysdl2

I would like to reflect the entire contents of and SDL2 Window across either or both of it's vertical or horizontal axes, using Python and PySDL2.

So far I can get it to here:

```
# window is an SDL_Window object created at runtime
screen_px = sdl2.ext.pixels2d(window.get_surface())
flipped = numpy.fliplr(screen_px)
screen_x_y = [1920, 1080]  # using flipped.shape also threw a seg fault
flipped_surf = numpy.zeros(screen_x_y)
flipped_surf[:] = flipped
```

Then I'm using a borrowed `blit()` function (that uses OpenGL to draw to the SDL_WINDOW object) to get `flipped_surf` onto the window before calling SDL's `window.swap()`.

This seems like it would work (it certainly produces the intended flipped pixel array), but when I attempt to `blit()` this code throws a `segmentation fault: 11` (I'm on OS X, in case this matters), with a warning from pysdl2 that `ExperimentalWarning: 'pixels2d' is in an experimental state.`

I'm very open to any solution that achieves this goal, all the same.

Comment: For a `TextureSprite` it's as simple as `sprite.flip ^= sdl2.SDL_FLIP_HORIZONTAL` (using the proper renderer). Maybe you can convert the surface to a texture (`sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory.from_surface`) and set the flag in the same way?